# Can you fill a shape with a canvas

Tags: konvajs

I would like to be able to fill a shape with a canvas; potentially to have one konva canvas generate an animation and update another konva canvas shape with it, masked inside a path. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Did you take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) 

This is not a textbook question for SO. We generally expect a code sample or images of what you tried to illustrate your issue. But it qualifies as a version of  the 'Is this even possible before I focus time on it' style of question which I have used myself so I'll pay back with some pointers.

Comment: For such use cases, it may be just simpler to clip the animated node.

Answer (score 1):

Its not totally clear what you actually want to do, but what you describe is probably achievable with Konva layers. You see Konva is a wrapper for HTML5 canvas and one of its features is layers - so you have one Konva instance that must have a minimum of  one layer but can have more. Konva cunningly uses a separate HTML5 canvas for each layer. See the example [here](https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/Layer_Management.html) in the Konva docs. If you hit F12 you can see the two canvas elements used, and there is a code sample too.

This gives a lot of power and some great performance management potential. And it is all baked in to Konva already so you will not have to manage multiple canvas instances in your own code.